# IP REGEX validation

Tags: python, regex, validation, loops

I've been trying to validate an inputted string (`sys argv[1]` in this case). I need to create a script that goes through a log file and matches the entries for source and destination ip with any argument input with the script. The kinds of valid inputs are either

- an IP or partial ip
- "any"(string which means all ip addresses in a given column).

So far I have the following code. Whenever I run the script in bash along with an argument (e.g any random number or word/alphabets etc) I get errors. Please let me know how I can fix them. Really appreciate a way to validate input against the IP address reg ex and the word any.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys,re

def ipcheck(ip):
    #raw patterns for "any" and "IP":
    ippattern = '([1-2]?[0-9]?[0-9]\.){1,3}([1-2]?[0-9]?[0-9])?'
    anypattern = any
    #Compiled patterns
    cippattern = re.compile(ippattern)
    canypattern = re.compile(any)
    #creating global variables for call outside function    
    global matchip
    global matchany
    #matching the compiled pattern 
    matchip = cippattern.match(ip)
    matchany = canypattern.match(ip)

new = sys.argv[1]
snew = str(new)
print type(snew)
ipcheck(new)
```

Also I tried to do it this way but it kept giving me errors, is it possible to pass 2 arguments to an if loop via the "OR |" operator? How would I do it this way?[/b]

```
#if (matchip | matchany) :  
    #print "the ip address is valid"
#else:
    #print "Invalid Destination IP"


Error
========================

user@bt:/home# ./ipregex.py a
<type 'str'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./ipregex.py", line 21, in <module>
ipcheck(new)
File "./ipregex.py", line 15, in ipcheck
matchany = re.match(anypattern,ip)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/re.py", line 137, in match
return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/re.py", line 237, in _compile
raise TypeError, "first argument must be string or compiled pattern"
TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern
```

==========================================================

## EDIT

I was trying to match the IP without compiling the regex. So I modified the script to do so. This resulted in the error:

### Error

```
user@bt:/home# ./ipregex.py a
<type 'str'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./ipregex.py", line 21, in <module>
ipcheck(new)
File "./ipregex.py", line 15, in ipcheck
matchany = anypattern.match(ip)
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'match'
```

==========================================================

## EDIT#2

I was able to reproduce my error in a simpler code version. What the heck am i doing wrong??????

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import re

def ipcheck(ip):
    anypattern = any
    cpattern = re.compile(anypattern)
    global matchany
    matchany = cpattern.match(ip)
    if matchany:
            print "ip match: %s" % matchany.group()
new = sys.argv[1]
ipcheck(new)
```

### ERROR

```
user@bt:/home# ./test.py any
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./test.py", line 14, in <module>
ipcheck(new)
File "./test.py", line 8, in ipcheck
cpattern = re.compile(anypattern)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/re.py", line 188, in compile
return _compile(pattern, flags)
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/re.py", line 237, in _compile
raise TypeError, "first argument must be string or compiled pattern"
TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern
```

Comment: Why would you only match IPv4, when IPv6 is increasingly relevant and required?

Comment: the log file which I am supposed to parse only contains ipv4 addresses.

Comment: Change `anypattern = any` to `anypattern = "*"` if you want to match everything.  If not, where is the variable `any` coming from?  At the moment, that script is trying to compile the built-in function `any()`.  http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any

Comment: oooh i finally see it! i cant believe I was mixing up built in function name with variables. i converted the anypattern = any to anypattern = 'any' (because i want to search for the exact string - any) and it works now! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `re.compile` you call the `match` function on the compiled object: `ippattern.match(ip)`.  Also, to get to matched ip from a [MatchObject](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MatchObject), use `MatchObject.group()`.  Fixed up your example some and it should now do what you need:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import re

def ipcheck(ip):
    ippattern_str = '(([1-2]?[\d]{0,2}\.){1,3}([1-2]?[\d]{0,2})|any)'

    ippattern = re.compile(ippattern_str)
    # ippattern is now used to call match, passing only the ip string
    matchip = ippattern.match(ip)
    if matchip:
        print "ip match: %s" % matchip.group()

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    ipcheck(sys.argv[1])
```

Some results:

```
[ 19:46 jon@hozbox ~/SO/python ]$ ./new.py 100.
ip match: 100.
[ 19:46 jon@hozbox ~/SO/python ]$ ./new.py 100.1.
ip match: 100.1.
[ 19:46 jon@hozbox ~/SO/python ]$ ./new.py 100.1.55.
ip match: 100.1.55.
[ 19:46 jon@hozbox ~/SO/python ]$ ./new.py 100.1.55.255
ip match: 100.1.55.255
[ 19:47 jon@hozbox ~/SO/python ]$ ./new.py any
ip match: any
[ 19:47 jon@hozbox ~/SO/python ]$ ./new.py foo
[ 19:47 jon@hozbox ~/SO/python ]$
```

Comment: I updated my code to include the compiled version of the regex. But even after doing it I still the error listed in the edit.

Comment: You need to use the return value of the `compile` call for `match`.  See my edits.

Comment: I copied and pasted your script and its working perfectly,I tried comparing it to mine and I still dont see any differences..dont know what I was doing wrong, maybe some hidden characters I couldnt see were messing it up?

Comment: Possible; its easy to typo 1 character in a regex and mess up the whole pattern.  Ive done it too many times to count :).

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression might be better:

```
((([1-2]?[0-9]?[0-9]\.){1,3}([1-2]?[0-9]?[0-9])?)|any)
```

It will match anything like:

```
127.0.0.1
127.0.0
127.0
127.
192.168.1.1
any
```

Your regular expression would have trouble with the above because it doesn't match `0`.

Edit:

I had missed the part about matching `any`.

This regular expression will match a few invalid addresses, however if you are just searching through log files that should be fine. You may wish to check out [this link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html) if you really need to be exact.

Comment: Seems like he also wants to match the word "any".  You should update the regex with "|any".

Comment: Appreciate the new and improved regex for IP validation.

@chown If you look at the commented lines in the middle of the script you will see that i tried to implement the "OR" | operator without any success like so:

#if (matchip | matchany) :  
    #print "the ip address is valid"
#else:
    #print "Invalid Destination IP"

do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @A Check my edits, the OR (for "any") is built in to the regex pattern, look at the last part of the regex pattern.

Comment: @chown thank you so much! :D but i suppose its not possible to include 2 conditions in an if loop. i know its possible using digits i.e if 2 > x < 5:

Comment: It is possible, do you want the "any" and the ip to be 2 different regex patterns seperate from each other?  Ill update to show an example.

Comment: combing them into one regex pattern is super clean and I like it better. But i was wondering just incase if i did have two variables( e.g ip regex and any regex in this case) would i be able to combine them within a single if statement without the need to nest? thank you once again

Comment: Not really actually, since you have to check if the match was found before calling `.group()` (or just put a `try/except` around the `.group()` so it wont error if there was no match when calling `.group()`).  Does that make sense?  Its hard to explain without my computer and examples (Im on my ipad at the moment), but the `re` docs have really good examples:  http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

Comment: hmm yes that definitely makes sense! really appreciate this. just one last question, i couldnt really see what was different between our code since we followed the same steps. and so i thought that maybe it was because my regex for the ip was off, well i made a simpler version of it and i was able to reproduce my error. So i would really really appreciate it if you could look at "Edit#2" and let me know what im doing wrong because i essentially followed all your steps. thank you.